# how to hide div tags inside ul tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to hide div tags inside ul tag. All tags are getting hidden if i use id of a ul tag. But i require first div tag to be shown and remaining div tags to be hidden.

html code is as follows:

```
<ul class="list inputControls ui-sortable" id="inputControlsContainer">
<div id="Radio" class="leaf">...</div>
<div id="Date" class="leaf">...</div>
<div id="Account" class="leaf">...</div>
<div id="Date1" class="leaf">...</div>
</ul>
```

script code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var child=document.getElementById("inputControlsContainer").style.display='none';
});
</script>
```

Comment: That HTML is invalid. `div` cannot be a direct child of `ul`. [The only valid direct child elements of `ul` are `li` and scripts.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

Comment: T.J. Crowder is correct, those should be `<li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [gt](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$('#inputControlsContainer .leaf:gt(0)').hide();
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5ue4/)

Comment: Your DEMO works beautiful as expected. Is there any solution by using "document.getElementById" and so on?

Comment: that is pure javascript, it is jquery code,you have to include jquery src file in your page

Comment: can you change your Fiddle DEMO and use that "document.getElementById" and hide those div elements

Comment: the gt() selector is of jquery, it will not work pure in javascript

Comment: so how to use that gt() greater than condition in javascript

Comment: sorry i have no idea as i use and prefer jquery over javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not)** along with **[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector)** selector:

```
$('#inputControlsContainer').find('.leaf').not(':first').hide();
```

---

Also, your HTML is currently invalid, you need to use `<li>` instead of `<div>` inside `<ul>`:

```
<ul class="list inputControls ui-sortable" id="inputControlsContainer">
    <li id="Radio" class="leaf">...</li>
    <li id="Date" class="leaf">...</li>
    <li id="Account" class="leaf">...</li>
    <li id="Date1" class="leaf">...</li>
</ul>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fF7ck/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to select li elements with the class selector, then bind an event handler to the click function. The bound function should find the next ul relevant to the selected element and call the toggle method upon it. By default the jquery toggle method will toggle the visibility of an element.

```
$(".current").click(function(){
  $(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
```

See this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ytXFQ/)